# Python, не получается сделать условие проверки для __add__ в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

вот код

```
class Water:
    
    def __add__(self, other):
            if other is Air():
                return Storm()
           
class Air:
    def __add__(self, other):
        if other is Water():
            return Storm()
class Storm:
    def __str__(self):
        return "шторм"
print(Water() + Air())
```

потихоньку знакомлюсь с python, делаю практическое задание и застрял...
нужно чтобы при сложении двух классов возвращался третий, подозреваю что надо как то более конкретно указать на   `Air()`,но не нагуглил как, пробовал подставлять для теста `if other is 1` и делать `print(Water() + 1)` тогда все работает и возвращается `Storm()`. Пожалуйста подскажите как реализовать эту проверку с классом.

Comment: `if isinstance(other,Air):`

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Или так: `if type(other) is Air:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор `a is b` фактически проверяет, что слева и справа стоит объект с одним `id`:

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

Поэтому когда вы проверяете `other is Air()` это эквивалентно такой проверке:

```
id(other) == id(Air())
```

Поскольку когда вы пишете `Air()` вы создаёте **новый экземпляр** класса `Air` такая проверка всегда будет возвращать `False`, поскольку адрес нового объекта будет отличаться от адреса уже существующего объекта.
Таким образом, чтобы проверить на совпадение **тип объекта** надо сравнивать не сам объект, а его тип, опять же с типом объекта, а **не с экземпляром** класса:

```
type(other) is Air # слева тип и справа тип, а не экземпляр
id(type(other)) == id(Air) # суть этой проверки
```

Либо, как предложил в комментарии splash58, такую же проверку можно сделать с помощью функции `isinstance`. Но фактически я думаю такая проверка делает тоже самое, что мой код выше, это просто "синтаксический сахар":

```
isinstance(other,Air)
```